# MacOS: heavy disk written and read by corespotlightd, how to fix?

Tags: macos, ssd, kernel, disk-utility

[image]

I just realize that my ssd health is down to 47%. Check the Activity Monitor on Mac shows that corespotlightd causes 10TB data read and write, and kernel_task causes another 2TB. This is just in less than 4 days. I restart the Mac and notice that corespotlightd will causes around 600GB to 800GB per day on disk written.

I have no idea what is going on. Any idea how could I trace the source of this problem and fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's part of Spotlight's indexing.

'Quick fix' System Prefs > Spotlight > Privacy.
Add all volumes to that, close, wait a couple of minutes, then reopen & remove them from the list. That will make Spotlight re-index, which may take several hours of high activity on corespotlightd, mds & mds_stores.

If it's still runaway after that, then try adding items you know change frequently; any sync structures, dropbox etc. &/or remove some of the busier categories from the Search Results tab, suggestions, documents, mail etc.

BTW, yes, I agree that's definitely runaway. Mine logs about 1GB per day.